# How to map nested JSON into Sencha model with associations?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

The associated Sencha Touch model is not mapped from JSON and I have no idea what I'm missing.

**Sencha Touch models**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Station', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

  config: {
    fields: [
      'name',
      {name: 'lat', type: 'float'},
      {name: 'long', type: 'float'}
    ],
    hasMany: {model: 'MyApp.model.Forecast', name: 'forecast'}
  }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Forecast', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

  config: {
    fields: [
      {name: 'date', type: 'date'},
      {name: 'sunshine', type: 'int'},
      {name: 'temperature', type: 'float'}
    ],
    belongsTo: 'MyApp.model.Station'
  }
});
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "name": "some name",
    "lat": 11.5716,
    "long": 4.68715,
    "forecast": [
        {
            "date": "2013-09-20 13:00:00",
            "sunshine": "11"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-09-20 14:00:00",
            "sunshine": "19"
        }
    ]
}
```

The simple fields are mapped just fine but the `forecast` array remains undefined. If I remove the `Forecast` model completely and just declare `forecast` as a simple field (see the following code snippet) the mapping works as expected. Any ideas why?

```
Ext.define('SunApp.model.Station', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

  config: {
    fields: [
      'name',
      {name: 'lat', type: 'float'},
      {name: 'long', type: 'float'},
      'forecast'
    ]
  }
});
```

Of course a working "solution" is better than nothing but the drawback is that I don't have a declared and thereby documented forecast model.

Comment: It’s been a while since I last attempted this, but back then I found it infeasible. I did eventually make Ext create the models, through some evil non-documented way, but then I couldn’t use them in XTemplate. I stuck to untyped simple fields. That was back in Ext JS 4.1 (or even 4.0) and your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're missing the [associationKey](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany-cfg-associationKey) configuration. There are definitely some quirks in how the associations work!

Comment: That's a good observation. However, the JSON data is not coming from an RDBMS with foreign keys, referential integrity and such i.e. I don't have association keys in JSON. I'd have to pre-process it and add some artificial ones just to make the Sencha mapper happy?

Comment: I think setting *associationKey : 'forecast'* might get you what you're after.

Comment: Actually, using exactly your example I see that station.forecast is a function - station.forecast() returns the internal store containing the associated records.

Comment: Correct! Don't even need the 'associationKey'. It's all nicely explained here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany. I'll still accept your answer.